# Nested Comments in C/C++

Tags: c++, c, comments

This is an interview question:-

> Write a C program which when compiled and run, prints out a message
>   indicating whether the compiler that it is compiled with, allows /* */
>   comments to nest.

The solution to this problem is given below :-

Sol:- you can have an integer variable nest:

```
int nest = /*/*/0*/**/1;
```

if it supports nested comments then the answer is 1 else answer is 0.

How is this working ? I don't understand the variable declaration.

Comment: Another pleasant piece of code is `strlen(/*/*/"*/*/"/*"/**/)`. This is cool exercise for sites like code golf, but highly inappropriate as an interview question.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

If the compiler doesn't allow nesting, the first `*/` will terminate the opening of the multiline comment, meaning the `0` won't be commented out. Written with some spaces:

```
int nest = /*/*/ 0 * /**/ 1;
```

resulting in the code

```
int nest = 0 * 1; // -> 0
```

If it allows nesting, it will be

```
int nest = /*/*/0*/**/ 1;
```

resulting in

```
int nest = 1;
```

Comment: It's not necessarily the last ever `*/` in the file that would terminate it if it supported nesting. If that were the case then `/**/0*1/**/` would not register as `0*1`, but rather as a comment. With or without nesting the compiler should see this as `0*1`

Comment: Amusingly, because the SO syntax highlighter doesn't support nesting, the highlighting in the final example suggests the semantics of the first example ^_^

Answer (score 11):

The short answer to "how is this working" is that:

```
int nest = /*/*/0*/**/1;
```

with nested comments becomes something like:

```
int nest = 
// /* (comment level 1) 
//    /*/ (comment level 2) 
//         0
//    */*
// */
1;
```

and without, the extra * makes it:

```
int nest = 
// /*/ (comment level 1) 
// */
        0
    *
// /*
// */
1;
```

or `0*1`.

Or, I think that's what's happening, but this question is pretty much a disaster. I entirely agree with Blagovest Buyukliev's comment.

Answer (score 4):

```
int nest = /*/*/0*/**/1;
```

### Nesting not allowed

If nesting is NOT allowed, the first comment's range is:

```
           vvvvv
int nest = /*/*/0*/**/1;
```

With that comment removed (gap left for readability - the C++ preprocessor substitutes a single space, not sure about C), the next comment seen is:

```
                  vvvv
int nest =      0*/**/1;
```

With that also removed:

```
int nest =      0*    1;
```

### Nesting allowed

Below, the `|+-` line shows the scope of the outer comment, and `vvvvvv` indicates teh scope of the inner comment.

```
           +---------+
           |         |
           | vvvvvv  |
int nest = /*/*/0*/**/1;
```

With those comments removed:

```
int nest =            1;
```

Answer (score 3):

If it supports nested comments, then you'll have (Stripping the comments):

```
int nest = 1;
```

If it does not, then you'll have (Stripping the comments):

```
int nest = 0 * 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

That is a big bag of loathsome hurt. My guess is that the third `/` possibly cancels the second multi-line comment block, rendering the `*` after the zero a multiplication, hence:

```
/* */0 * /* */ 1 == 0 * 1 == 0 // ==> nested comments aren't supported.
```

Answer (score 0):

If the compiler understands nested comments, it will just strip the `/*/*/0*/**/` part and leave you with the `int nest = 1`.

Otherwise, it will see `int nest = 0*1` and `0 * 1 == 0`.